# django template - displaying images in table

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I can't get images (or image links) to display on template.  Everything else is working on the template but the image "render_thumbnail", which is defined in a custom model method. What am I doing wrong?  -btw the render_thumbnail works on another template when I am working only with the Images table, and am displaying using  -   images.render_thumbnail.  Thanks.

Models.py

```
class Listings(models.Model):
    createdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expirydate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    broker_y_n = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, choices=broker, default='n')
    listing_type = models.ForeignKey(ListingType)
    listing_status = models.ForeignKey(ListingStatus, default=3)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)
    #tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    #albums = models.ManyToManyField(Album, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #rating = models.IntegerField(default=50)
    width = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    listings = models.ForeignKey(Listings)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Save image dimensions
        super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        im = PImage.open(pjoin(MEDIA_ROOT, self.image.name))
        self.width, self.height = im.size
        # large thumbnail
        fn, ext = os.path.splitext(self.image.name)
        im.thumbnail((256,256), PImage.ANTIALIAS)
        thumb_fn = fn + "-thumb2" + ext
        tf2 = NamedTemporaryFile()
        im.save(tf2.name, "JPEG")
        self.thumbnail2.save(thumb_fn, File(open(tf2.name)), save=False)
        tf2.close()
        # small thumbnail
        im.thumbnail((60,60), PImage.ANTIALIAS)
        thumb_fn = fn + "-thumb" + ext
        tf = NamedTemporaryFile()
        im.save(tf.name, "JPEG")
        self.thumbnail.save(thumb_fn, File(open(tf.name)), save=False)
        tf.close()
        super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    def size(self):
        # Image size #
        return "%s x %s" % (self.width, self.height)
    def render_thumbnail(self):
        return mark_safe("""<a href = "/media/%s"><img border="0" alt=""     src="/media/%s" /></a>""" % ((self.image.name, self.thumbnail.name)))
    #render_thumbnail.allow_tags = True
    def render_thumbnail2(self):
        return mark_safe("""<a href = "/media/%s"><img border="0" alt="" src="/media/%s" /></a>""" % ((self.image.name, self.thumbnail2.name)))
    #render_thumbnail.allow_tags = True
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.image.name
```

View.py

```
def details_customer(request, user_id):
    customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, user=user_id)
    cusnum=customer.id
    image = Image.objects.all()    
    listings = Listings.objects.filter(customer=cusnum).values(
        'id',
        'price',
        'listing_type__desc',
        'listing_status',
        'listing_status__desc',
        'canoekayak__builder',
        'image__title',
        'image__thumbnail',
        'image__render_thumbnail',        
        )
    context = Context({
        'title': 'Details',
        'customer': customer,
        'image' : image,        
        'listings' : listings,
        })
    return render_to_response('bsmain/details.html', context)
```

Template table

```
<TABLE id="some_id">    
<TBODY>
    {% load humanize %}
    {% for row in listings %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
        <td align="right">{{row.price|intcomma}}</td>
        <td>{{ row.listing_type__desc}}</td>
        <td>{{ row.listing_status}}</td>
        <td>{{ row.listing_status__desc}}</td>
        <td>{{ row.canoekayak__builder}}</td>
        <td>{{ row.image__title}}</td>
        <td>{{ row.image__thumbnail}}</td
        <td>{{ row.image__render_thumbnail}}</td            
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</TBODY>
```

Comment: What do you get instead of the images? I suspect your `<img../>` tag gets unintentionally escaped.

Comment: 1. use queryset directly w/o appending `values`
2. dont hardcode src like '/media/', try unicode(image.thumbnail) and image.thumbnail.url

Comment: hey 9000, I get a blank table cell, as in nothing, nada.

Comment: Try to call your `render_thumbnail()` from Python shell.

Comment: There's something you're not showing us here. That `Listing.objects.values` call will fail with a `FieldError` when you try and include `image__render_thumbnail`, as `render_thumbnail` is a method, not a field.

Comment: I believe you should use something like {{ row.image.render_thumbnail }} not the __.  The same would be true for accessing the other image fields.  I also agree that the values call may be unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make your code simpler, I would like to recommend to use application [django-tables2](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2). This approach can solve all your issues about generating tables.

As documentation sais:

> django-tables2 simplifies the task of turning sets of data into HTML
>   tables. It has native support for pagination and sorting. It does for
>   HTML tables what django.forms does for HTML forms. e.g.
>
> Its features include:
>
> - Any iterable can be a data-source, but special support for Django querysets is included.
> - The builtin UI does not rely on JavaScript.
> - Support for automatic table generation based on a Django model.
> - Supports custom column functionality via subclassing.
> - Pagination.
> - Column based table sorting.
> - Template tag to enable trivial rendering to HTML.
> - Generic view mixin for use in Django 1.3.
>
> Creating a table is as simple as:
>
> ```
> import django_tables2 as tables
>
> class SimpleTable(tables.Table):
>     class Meta:
>         model = Simple
> ```
>
> This would then be used in a view:
>
> ```
> def simple_list(request):
>     queryset = Simple.objects.all()
>     table = SimpleTable(queryset)
>     return render_to_response("simple_list.html", {"table": table},
>                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
> ```
>
> And finally in the template:
>
> ```
> {% load django_tables2 %} 
> {% render_table table %}
> ```
>
> This example shows
>   one of the simplest cases, but django-tables2 can do a lot more! Check
>   out the [documentation](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for more details.

It is also possible to use dictionary instead of queryset.

For displaying images in table cells you can use custom table column HtmlColumn

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
import django_tables2 as tables

from pytils.numeral import get_plural
class HtmlColumn(tables.Column):
    def render(self, value):
        return mark_safe(value)
```

or create new ImageColumn in the same way and transfer only *src* attribute, instead of whole *img* tag.

Comment: Rasmus .. thanks for telling me about django-tables2. I will check it out.  I have been considering datatables, but have not made any decisions yet.

Comment: If you mean jQuery lib http://datatables.net/, the best decision is to use both of them. Django-table2 will let you organize server-side part, datatables client-side part.